# How to mock method call inside another method call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking, stub

I have the following code:

```
 def do_something(param1, param2)
    "hello" if current_page? param2
  end
```

The application code above works however when I do this in my helper spec:

```
allow(helper).to receive(:current_page?).and_return(true)
```

it does not work it says `You cannot use helpers that need to determine the current page unless your view context provides a Request object in a #request method`

but when I do

```
 allow(self).to receive(:current_page?).and_return(true)
```

it works. How is this happening? Isn't `self` in this case the helper spec class? Why can't I refer to the helper explicitly?

Comment: Can you post more context? Right now we do not even know the scope of of this line of code

Answer (score 0):

I guess you call the expect as below

```rb
RSpec.describe ApplicationHelper, type: :helper do
  describe "#hello" do
    it "returns hello" do
      expect(do_something).to eq("hello")
    end
  end
end
```

Whenever you `describe` a test case, you create a `RSpec::Rails::{type}ExampleGroup`, here type is `helper` so you create a [RSpec::Rails::HelperExampleGroup](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/main/spec/rspec/rails/configuration_spec.rb#L183-L193), this example_group [wrap a helper that is your ApplicationHelper](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/main/spec/rspec/rails/example/helper_example_group_spec.rb#L54). Beside that, this `example_group` could respond_to all methods of your helper

```rb
RSpec.describe ApplicationHelper, type: :helper do
  # ...
  it "returns hello" do
    puts self # RSpec::ExampleGroups::ApplicationHelper::...
    puts self.respond_to?(:do_something)  # true
    puts self.respond_to?(:current_page?)# true

    puts self.helper.is_a?(ApplicationHelper) # true
  end
```

Here `current_page?` is special method which belongs to module `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper` and this is a guy raise the error you've got.

So when you call directly `expect(do_something)` that you're calling `expect(example_group.do_something)` and so that the object call the method `current_page?` inside the method `do_something` is the example_group and if you're not mock this method on the example_group object, this will raise error. That why your test case will pass when you mock `allow(self).to receive(:current_page?).and_return(true)`.

Now your test case will pass if you mock this method on the `helper` method and also use the `helper` to call `do_something` since `helper.do_something` equivalent to `self.helper.do_something` that is actually `example_group.helper.do_something`

```rb
allow(helper).to receive(:current_page?).and_return(true)
expect(helper.do_something).to eq("hello")
```